# Deserialize JSON Android Xamarin

Tags: android, json, api, xamarin, serialization

I'm trying to fill every string from JSON that i got from API.

```
"{
    \"UseID\":\"sbm_deni\",
    \"UseNam\":\"Deni Andrean\",
    \"UsePass\":null,
    \"UseDep\":\"IT\",
    \"UseLev\":\"1\",
    \"UseEmail\":null,
    \"UseComCod\":null,
    \"UseIC\":null,
    \"UseTel\":null,
    \"BusFunc\":\"SYSTEM-ADMIN\",
    \"CreDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",
    \"CreUser\":null,
    \"ChgDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",
    \"ChgUser\":null,
    \"isDelegate\":false,
    \"UsePlant\":\"2300\",
    \"StartPage\":\"Dashboard/Index\",
    \"isWindowsAuth\":false,
    \"Domain\":null,\"isActiveAcc\":false,
    \"LastLoginDevice\":null,
    \"ApprovalGroup\":\"\",
    \"isAuthoriseSeeNumber\":true
}"
```

I got JSON from `var result = await vmsapi.LoginUser(model);`
but how to fill,

```
string a = USE.ID
string b = USE.Nam
```

hope someone can help.. thanks.

Comment: Is above code part of Json data? If you have complete code, you can use https://json2csharp.com/ tool to convert to C# USE class , then you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to get the List<USE>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deserialize a JSON-object like this:

```
{
  "UserID":"123",
  "UserName":"John Doe"
}
```

Add a class to your models:

```
public class UserModel 
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then use [Newtonsoft JSON.Net framework](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) to deserialize:

```
string result = await vmsapi.LoginUser(model);

var deserialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserModel>>(result);

foreach (UserModel user in deserialized)
{
   string a = user.UserID;
   string b = user.UserName;
}
```

Comment: @DennyAndrean You're Welcome. If it was helpful could you mark the answer as accepted please?